# Will queued Sidekiq jobs reload code?

Tags: ruby, queue, jobs, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq to process a lot of jobs which all write to one file. This group of work has been running for over 24 hours, which is not a problem. I'm taking precautions to prevent restarting this process.

I would like to know if I update the code which the jobs rely on, will the queued work be affected by these changes or will the jobs continue to use the old code?

*If it matters, all methods have been written as class methods which exist on the same object. Any input is welcomed. Thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update the code and restart sidekiq, the queued jobs will use the new code.